# Android SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I'm trying to put a Sliding Drawer to my activity using [this](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/) tutorial. My app is for Android 2.1-update1 (API 7). When i create a xml layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
    <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minWidth="100px"/>
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/strFilter" />
    <Button android:text="Filtriraj" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:baselineAligned="true" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:clipChildren="true" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="3dip">
            <TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/lblOd" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="5dip"></TextView>
            <TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:text="@string/lblDatum" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrowdown"></TextView>
            <TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:text="@string/lblTekst" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I got an exception when switch to "design view" - Graphical Layout. Error is

```
ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found: - SlidingDrawer
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Switch design view to Android 3.0 then it works, somekind of a bug in ADT. If you run it in emulator, then code works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll be designing/laying out things for 3.0, when your app will be running on MILLIONS of 2.x devices instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualifying the SlidingDrawer class name (android.widget.SlidingDrawer) resolved this issue for me.  This only seems to work for 2.1-update1 and above however.

Also, be sure that you set the drawer handle to a valid child of the drawer.